# How to find an XML tag using a reference in another XML tag's attribute value and display it?

Tags: html, xml, xslt, transform

I want to generate an HTML output for following XML. But I don't want to display everything in the XML but some text within the specific tags.

Here is the XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE article SYSTEM "DTD.dtd">
<at dtd-version="1.0" article-type="RA">
  <first>
    <a-meta>
      <a-cat>
        <sg sg-type="A Type">
          <sub>RA</sub>
        </sg>
        <sg sg-type="Cat">
          <sub>OSD</sub>
        </sg>
        <sg sg-type="Class">
          <sub>OS</sub>
          <sg>
            <sub>IT</sub>
            <sg>
              <sub>Air-SE</sub>
              <sub>Sea-IP</sub>
              <sub>BC</sub>
            </sg>
          </sg>
          <sg>
            <sub>Regions</sub>
            <sg>
              <sub>AO</sub>
            </sg>
          </sg>
          <sg>
            <sub>BC - O</sub>
          </sg>
        </sg>
      </a-cat>
      <t-group>
        <a-title>ABC</a-title>
        <alt-title alt-title-type="r-h">abc</alt-title>
      </t-group>
      <c-group>
        <ctrb ctrb-type="au" corresp="yes">
          <role content-type="1" />
          <name>
            <sname>Sname1</sname>
            <g-names>Fname1</g-names>
            <prefix>Ms.</prefix>
          </name>
          <ctrb-id ctrb-id-type="orcid" specific-use="authenticated">123-456-789</ctrb-id>
          <degrees>PhD</degrees>
          <email>email1@email.com</email>
          <xref ref-type="aff" rid="aff1" />
        </ctrb>
        <ctrb ctrb-type="au">
          <role content-type="2" />
          <name>
            <sname>Sname2</sname>
            <g-names>Fname2</g-names>
          </name>
          <email>email2@email.com</email>
          <xref ref-type="aff" rid="aff2" />
        </ctrb>
        <ctrb ctrb-type="au">
          <role content-type="3" />
          <name>
            <sname>Sname3</sname>
            <g-names>Fname3</g-names>
          </name>
          <email>email3@email.com</email>
          <xref ref-type="aff" rid="aff3" />
        </ctrb>
        <ctrb ctrb-type="au">
          <role content-type="4" />
          <name>
            <sname>Sname4</sname>
            <g-names>Fname4</g-names>
          </name>
          <email>email4@email.com</email>
          <xref ref-type="aff" rid="aff4" />
        </ctrb>
        <ctrb ctrb-type="au">
          <role content-type="5" />
          <name>
            <sname>Sname5</sname>
            <g-names>Fname5</g-names>
          </name>
          <email>email5@email.com</email>
          <xref ref-type="aff" rid="aff5" />
        </ctrb>
        <ctrb ctrb-type="au">
          <role content-type="6" />
          <name>
            <sname>Sname6</sname>
            <g-names>Fname6</g-names>
          </name>
          <email>email6@email.com</email>
          <xref ref-type="aff" rid="aff6" />
        </ctrb>
        <ctrb ctrb-type="au">
          <role content-type="7" />
          <name>
            <sname>Sname7</sname>
            <g-names>Fname7</g-names>
          </name>
          <email>email7@email.com</email>
          <xref ref-type="aff" rid="aff7" />
        </ctrb>
        <ctrb ctrb-type="au">
          <role content-type="8" />
          <name>
            <sname>Sname8</sname>
            <g-names>Fname8</g-names>
          </name>
          <email>email8@email.com</email>
          <xref ref-type="aff" rid="aff8" />
        </ctrb>
        <ctrb ctrb-type="au">
          <role content-type="9" />
          <name>
            <sname>Sname9</sname>
            <g-names>Fname9</g-names>
          </name>
          <email>email9@email.com</email>
          <xref ref-type="aff" rid="aff9" />
        </ctrb>
        <ctrb ctrb-type="au">
          <role content-type="10" />
          <name>
            <sname>Sname10</sname>
            <g-names>Fname10</g-names>
          </name>
          <email>email10@email.com</email>
          <xref ref-type="aff" rid="aff10" />
        </ctrb>
        <ctrb ctrb-type="edit">
          <name>
            <sname>SnameE1</sname>
            <g-names>FnameE1</g-names>
          </name>
          <degrees>PhD</degrees>
          <email>email1@mail.com</email>
          <role>EIC - OS</role>
          <xref ref-type="aff" rid="aff11" />
        </ctrb>

        <ctrb ctrb-type="edit">
          <name>
            <sname>SnameE2</sname>
            <g-names>FnameE2</g-names>
          </name>
          <degrees>BS</degrees>
          <email>email2@mail.com</email>
          <role>AE - OS</role>
          <xref ref-type="aff" rid="aff12" />
        </ctrb>
        <aff id="aff1">
          <institution>Uni1</institution>
          <adr-line content-type="adrline1">Addr Line 1</adr-line>
          <country>COUNTRY</country>
          <adr-line content-type="city">city1</adr-line>
          <adr-line content-type="zip">1000</adr-line>
          <phone content-type="primary">+123456789</phone>
        </aff>
        <aff id="aff2">
          <institution>Inst1</institution>
        </aff>
        <aff id="aff3">
          <institution>Inst2</institution>
        </aff>
        <aff id="aff4">
          <institution>Inst4</institution>
        </aff>
        <aff id="aff5">
          <institution>Inst5</institution>
        </aff>
        <aff id="aff6">
          <institution>Inst6</institution>
        </aff>
        <aff id="aff7">
          <institution>Inst7</institution>
        </aff>
        <aff id="aff8">
          <institution>Inst8</institution>
        </aff>
        <aff id="aff9">
          <institution>Inst9</institution>
        </aff>
        <aff id="aff10">
          <institution>Inst10</institution>
        </aff>
        <aff id="aff11">
          <institution>Uni2</institution>
          <institution content-type="position">Professor</institution>
          <institution content-type="dept">Department of BO</institution>
          <adr-line content-type="addrline1">480 MCP</adr-line>
          <country>LK</country>
          <adr-line content-type="city">City2</adr-line>
          <adr-line content-type="state">AP</adr-line>
        </aff>
        <aff id="aff12">
          <institution>Uni3</institution>
          <institution content-type="position">Associate Professor</institution>
          <institution content-type="dept">Department of GS</institution>
          <adr-line content-type="addrline1">1 Circle</adr-line>
          <adr-line content-type="addrline2">Building 4</adr-line>
          <country>LK</country>
          <adr-line content-type="city">SA</adr-line>
          <adr-line content-type="state">TC</adr-line>
          <adr-line content-type="zipcode">75289</adr-line>
        </aff>
      </c-group>
      <history>
        <date date-type="received">
          <day>18</day>
          <month>08</month>
          <year>2013</year>
        </date>
        <date date-type="rev-recd">
          <day>16</day>
          <month>07</month>
          <year>2016</year>
        </date>
        <date date-type="rev-recd">
          <day>07</day>
          <month>02</month>
          <year>2016</year>
        </date>
        <date date-type="rev-recd">
          <day>22</day>
          <month>10</month>
          <year>2015</year>
        </date>
        <date date-type="accepted">
          <day>12</day>
          <month>06</month>
          <year>2016</year>
        </date>
      </history>
      <kwd-group>
        <kwd>SI</kwd>
        <kwd>Air</kwd>
        <kwd>Bub</kwd>
      </kwd-group>
      <funding-group />
      <counts>
        <fig-count count="0" />
      </counts>
      <c-meta-group>
        <c-meta>
          <meta-value>MK</meta-value>
        </c-meta>
        <c-meta>
          <meta-name>Black and White Image Count</meta-name>
          <meta-value>0</meta-value>
        </c-meta>
        <c-meta>
          <meta-name>Color Image Count</meta-name>
          <meta-value>0</meta-value>
        </c-meta>
        <c-meta>
          <meta-name>Production Notes</meta-name>
          <meta-value>Hi,

mail goes here.

Thanks.
</meta-value>
        </c-meta>
        <c-meta id="SF">
          <meta-name>Special Feature Title</meta-name>
          <meta-value>BEP</meta-value>
        </c-meta>
        <c-meta id="Pub_charge">
          <meta-name>PC</meta-name>
          <meta-value>123</meta-value>
        </c-meta>
        <c-meta id="Discount">
          <meta-name>Discount</meta-name>
          <meta-value>55%</meta-value>
        </c-meta>
        <c-meta id="Explanation">
          <meta-name>Explanation</meta-name>
          <meta-value>SFA</meta-value>
        </c-meta>
      </c-meta-group>
    </a-meta>
  </first>
</at>
```

I want to display the text from the XML file as the order given below (only text from few tags need to be displayed).

```
<ctrb ctrb-type="edit">
    <name>
        <sname>SnameE1</sname>
            <g-names>FnameE1</g-names>
    </name>
    <xref ref-type="aff" rid="aff11" />
</ctrb>

<aff id="aff11">
          <institution>Uni2</institution>
</aff>


<ctrb ctrb-type="edit">
          <name>
            <sname>SnameE2</sname>
            <g-names>FnameE2</g-names>
          </name>
          <xref ref-type="aff" rid="aff12" />
 </ctrb>

<aff id="aff12">
          <institution>Uni3</institution>
 </aff>
```

To search each `<ctrb ctrb-type="edit">` tag's respective `<aff>` tag, need to use the reference in the `<xref>` tag's rid attribute value text. I am not sure if this can be done using XSL since I'm not an XSL expert. If someone of you can help me on this I would really appreciate it.

Here is the HTML output I need (simplified):

```
<p>FnameE1 SnameE1</p>
<p>Uni2</p>
<br/>
<p>FnameE2 SnameE2</p>
<p>Uni3</p>
```

So far what I wrote is this (simplified):

```
<p>Name: <xsl:value-of select="/at/first/a-meta/c-group/ctrb[@ctrb-type='edit']/name/g-names" />&#x00A0;<xsl:value-of select="/article/front/article-meta/contrib-group/contrib[@contrib-type='editor']/name/sname" /></p>
<p>Degree: <xsl:value-of select="/at/first/a-meta/c-group/ctrb[@ctrb-type='edit']/degrees" /></p>
<p>Email: <xsl:value-of select="/at/first/a-meta/c-group/ctrb[@ctrb-type='edit']/emai" /></p>
<p>Role: <xsl:value-of select="/at/first/a-meta/c-group/ctrb[@ctrb-type='edit']/role" /></p>
```

I want to list down `<ctrb ctrb-type="edit">` tag's text and find and display respective `<aff>` tag of each `<ctrb ctrb-type="edit">` under every `<ctrb ctrb-type="edit">` tag text.
Any logic or guidance to do it will really big help for me.

If you are not clear about my question please let me know.

Comment: Please post the exact HTML result you expect to get by transforming the example input. Minimizing the example to only what's required to demonstrate the problem would be a welcome improvement.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback, I've added the required simplified sample output after the transformation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is still confusing because the expected output does not match what you tried to do.

Anyway, try this as your starting point:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:key name="aff" match="aff" use="@id"/>

<xsl:template match="/at">
    <html>
        <body>
            <xsl:for-each select="first/a-meta/c-group/ctrb[@ctrb-type='edit']">
                <p>
                    <xsl:value-of select="name/sname"/>
                    <xsl:text>, </xsl:text>
                    <xsl:value-of select="name/g-names"/>
                </p>
                <p>
                    <xsl:value-of select="key('aff', xref/@rid)/institution"/>
                </p>
                <br/>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </body>
    </html>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Applied to your input example, the result will be:

```
<html>
   <body>
      <p>SnameE1, FnameE1</p>
      <p>Uni2</p>
      <br>
      <p>SnameE2, FnameE2</p>
      <p>Uni3</p>
      <br>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you so much. This is what I wanted. I've simplified my requirement, that may be the reason for confusion. :-)